# How to restore Windows "Mount"

Tags: iso-image, winrar

After I installed WinRAR when I right click a ISO I no longer get the "Mount" option, so, How can I restore it?

PS: Using Windows 7 Pro, full update

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have a "mount" option by default.  If you were able to mount .iso files this was provided by a third-party application.  What application provides this functionality?

Comment: @Ramhound no, it was a native! I just performed a clean install of win 7 pro, updated everything, installed VS 2013 from a iso, THEN installed WinRAR! im sure of it!

Comment: You are mistaken. Windows 8 was the first version of Windows to allow you to mount an image using the built in feature.

Comment: I'm with @Ramhound. Windows 7 does not have a native mounting tool.